# Join table on a date between two dates in the target table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

```
tbl_TimeEntries 
   EmployeeID int,
   StartDateTime datetime,
   EndDateTime datetime

tbl_Crew_Employees
   CrewID,
   EmployeeID,
   StartDate,
   EndDate
```

I also have a query that produces the number of hours worked per employee per day, but I also want to include the crew the employee was on for that day.

```
SELECT  tbl_TimeEntries.EmployeeID, 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0
                     / 60.0) as Hours,
        CAST(StartDateTime AS date) as WorkDate
FROM    tbl_TimeEntries 
GROUP BY tbl_TimeEntries.EmployeeID, CAST(StartDateTime AS date)
ORDER BY CAST(StartDateTime AS date)
```

I'm not sure how to include the CrewID in this query because the tbl_Crew_Employees uses a StartDate and EndDate (meaning the employee was on this crew from StartDate to EndDate). I would either need to expand the StartDate/EndDate range or use some sort of SQL magic of which I am unaware.

Here is a sample of the data from the tbl_Crew_Employees, tbl_TimeEntries and the current query with the desired column data added. EmployeeID 88 is represented on two different crews in the sample.

```
CrewID  EmployeeID  StartDate   EndDate

13      11          2013-03-30  2013-05-12
12      88          2013-01-02  2013-04-18
12      66          2013-01-02  2013-06-30
13      88          2013-04-19  2013-04-21
11      111         2013-01-02  2013-04-28

EmployeeID  StartDateTime       EndDateTime
11          2013-04-18 08:00    2013-04-18 12:00
11          2013-04-18 12:30    2013-04-18 18:30
111         2013-04-18 10:00    2013-04-18 12:00
111         2013-04-18 12:30    2013-04-18 18:30
88          2013-04-18 11:00    2013-04-18 12:00
88          2013-04-18 12:30    2013-04-18 19:30
66          2013-04-18 10:00    2013-04-18 12:00
66          2013-04-18 12:30    2013-04-18 18:30
11          2013-04-20 08:00    2013-04-20 12:00
11          2013-04-20 12:30    2013-04-20 18:00
111         2013-04-20 10:00    2013-04-20 12:00
111         2013-04-20 12:30    2013-04-20 18:30
88          2013-04-20 11:00    2013-04-20 12:00
88          2013-04-20 12:30    2013-04-20 19:30
66          2013-04-20 10:00    2013-04-20 12:00
66          2013-04-20 12:30    2013-04-20 17:00

EmployeeID  Hours   WorkDate        CrewID(desired)
11          10.00   2013-04-18      13
88          8.00    2013-04-18      12
66          8.00    2013-04-18      12
111         8.00    2013-04-18      11
11          7.50    2013-04-20      13
88          8.00    2013-04-20      13
66          6.50    2013-04-20      12
111         8.00    2013-04-20      11
```

Comment: Can you please add a few rows of sample data?

Comment: Also, please show what you would like the end result to look like.

Comment: how about some test date for TimeEntries

Comment: and can a worked flow between crews on the same day?

Comment: A crew member can only work on one crew per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_TimeEntries.employeeid
    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0 / 60.0) AS HOURS
    ,CAST(StartDateTime AS DATE) AS WorkDate
    ,tbl_Crew_Employees.crewid
FROM tbl_TimeEntries 
INNER JOIN tbl_Crew_Employees ON tbl_timeentries.employeeid = tbl_Crew_Employees.employeeid 
    AND startdatetime >= startdate 
    AND enddatetime <= enddate
GROUP BY tbl_TimeEntries.employeeid
        ,tbl_Crew_Employees.crewid
        ,CAST(tbl_TimeEntries.StartDateTime AS DATE)
ORDER BY WorkDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be a simple join.

```
declare @tbl_Crew_Employees table(CrewID int, EmployeeID int, StartDate date, EndDate date)
insert into @tbl_Crew_Employees
values
(13,11,'2013-03-30','2013-05-12'),
(12,88,'2013-01-02','2013-04-18'),
(12,66,'2013-01-02','2013-06-30'),
(13,88,'2013-04-19','2013-04-21'),
(11,111,'2013-01-02','2013-04-28')

declare @tbl_TimeEntries table (EmployeeID int, StartDateTime datetime, EndDateTime datetime)
insert into @tbl_TimeEntries
values
(11,'2013-04-18 08:00','2013-04-18 12:00'),
(11,'2013-04-18 12:30','2013-04-18 18:30'),
(111,'2013-04-18 10:00','2013-04-18 12:00'),
(111,'2013-04-18 12:30','2013-04-18 18:30'),
(88,'2013-04-18 11:00','2013-04-18 12:00'),
(88,'2013-04-18 12:30','2013-04-18 19:30'),
(66,'2013-04-18 10:00','2013-04-18 12:00'),
(66,'2013-04-18 12:30','2013-04-18 18:30'),
(11,'2013-04-20 08:00','2013-04-20 12:00'),
(11,'2013-04-20 12:30','2013-04-20 18:00'),
(111,'2013-04-20 10:00','2013-04-20 12:00'),
(111,'2013-04-20 12:30','2013-04-20 18:30'),
(88,'2013-04-20 11:00','2013-04-20 12:00'),
(88,'2013-04-20 12:30','2013-04-20 19:30'),
(66,'2013-04-20 10:00','2013-04-20 12:00'),
(66,'2013-04-20 12:30','2013-04-20 17:00')

SELECT  
    t.EmployeeID, 
    c.CrewID,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.StartDateTime, t.EndDateTime) / 60.0
                     / 60.0) ,
        CAST(t.StartDateTime AS date)
FROM    @tbl_TimeEntries t
INNER JOIN 
    @tbl_Crew_Employees c on 
    c.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID
    and c.StartDate <= cast(t.StartDateTime as date)
    and c.EndDate >= cast(t.EndDateTime as date)
GROUP BY t.EmployeeID, CAST(t.StartDateTime AS date), c.CrewID
ORDER BY CAST(t.StartDateTime AS date)
```

Comment: Actually, that won't work. The join must also include the date from both sides. The employee was on different crews on different dates, your solution does not provide for that.

Comment: based on the lack of sample data, then i assume the dates must equal. See edit. If they can flow between days, we can add spanning logic--you just need to clarify

Comment: @scsimon you have some syntax errors - do you want to correct them, or should I?

Comment: Looks like you want non-overlapping from the sample data @Paul... see edit.